# Can a jinn do something for you?

Tags: jinn

My friend told me that a man in his town control a jinn and the jinn advices him at any time. When he wants to do something, he contacts the jinn and gets advice from him.

Is this true?

Comment: yes it is , but it is haraam for us to get into contact with jinns except for when they hold a person captive.

Comment: There is almost zero possible human interaction with a Jinn. Whoever thinks Jinns can help them and pray to them for help, they're committing Shirk. However Jinn may be able to see and hear humans. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Associating with Jinns is called magic. According to Islam it is forbidden to ask for help from jinns and it is Blasphemy
[http://www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa468)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, some people can do this, but rarely.
It's prohibited, but to be able to do this they have to disbelieve (in God), and do some nasty things.
You can protect yourself from them, by reading and memorizing Quran, and some Duaa, and of course you can seek help from professional peoples.

Comment: although your answer is right but better to add some Islamic references.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know a trusted English source.
But, here is a trusted Arabic source, it can be translated via Google Translator, for thus who don't know Arabic.
http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=109757

Comment: how you know this is a trusted source?

Comment: You know, when you read too much. Plus the site belong to The Ministry of Awqaf and Islamic Affairs in Qatar. Besides that we look for the person who said the Fatwa, if available.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not Haraam, that's OK, only not encouraged as it can probably yields into many catastrophes, specifically when most of the times only the satanic Jinns are interested in having such relations and entering the territory would make it hard to release from them, they will force their correspondence to wrong actions. Also yes abusing the Jinns and hurting them or killing them is forbidden, likewise doing miracles based on their knowledge and power and making people go astray both are forbidden.

Other than that who ever said having relation with believer Jinns is Haram? Even according to Shia Fiqh marriage between Jinn and Human is allowed, although yet discouraged. If the woman is to be a human it is more strictly discouraged and if there is no other choice she is better to ask for permission for Talaq (divorce), if she likes. [استفتائات من آیت‌الله بهجت]

But all in all, live your life, these are not safe territories for us regular Muslims, they might hurt you and your family if you do anything wrong against them, even if not by intention.

Comment: "...or killing them is forbidden..."Can Jinns be killed?

Comment: @NUnnikrishnan, yes but please don't ask how :) Meanwhile, only Iblis the Satan is given time to live for a specified time, other than him the other Jins who can be believer or disbeliever might be killed by humans and there are many Ahadeeth narrating such happenings.

Comment: would have loved asking :) By the way, it'll be great if you can mention some Ahadith (or a link).

Answer (score -1):

My dear muslim brothers and sisters one day afternoon around 2pm at work no one was around I was reciting kalima tayaba and surah fateha he came infront at a distance bright super white I could clearly see face and structure I started welcoming come Please sit and then all started he took me to moon I took the lunar soil in my hands ears were shut I cant explain I was very well awake situation was unlike sleeping very well awake I always wanted to see roza rasool also from beneath it got fulfilled Alhamdulilah I dont know what price I have to pay but I am honest why should I lie

Comment: Call me if any inquiries 1pm to 4pm 65984680